# Scrollable.of() was called with a context that does not contain a Scrollable widget

Tags: flutter, overflow, scaffold

I/flutter ( 5136): Another exception was thrown: Scrollable.of() was called with a context that does not contain a Scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 5136): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 199495 pixels on the bottom.

The project appear this problem after i push the project to github. ALL of my page become like this
[image]

before push to the github the project is working properly, anyone can help me for this? Since I can't find any solution for this problem

Comment: please share the code of how you are using it.

Comment: I found the same issue when update Flutter to the latest version. To fix it you need to wrap the Slidable Widget in a ListView.Builder.

Answer (score 12):

Like Leandro Ariel, encountered the bug when upgrading flutter to 3.7. Wrapping the slidable with `ListView.builder` fix the bug but come with some undesirable scroll effects, wrapping with `Scrollable` did a better job:

```
Scrollable(
  viewportBuilder: (BuildContext context, ViewportOffset position) => your widget here,
);
```

Comment: update: this presented problems in tests.
but I'm investigating. in the app the error disappeared.

Comment: Is that actually a bug or some changes in Flutter? Is it reported to Flutter?

Comment: It seems to be a change in Flutter 3.7. There is an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115705 .

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap your widget inside SingleChildScrollView.

SingleChildScrollView(
child: YOUR_WIDGET),

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue when update Flutter to the latest version.
To fix it you need to wrap the Slidable Widget in a ListView.Builder. Something like this:

```
ListView.builder(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          YOUR_SLIDABLE()
        }
);
```